# How to use urlencode to handle two question marks in url in php

Tags: php, urlencode

I have tried to understand and use urlencode, but the problem can't be solved.

The code is:
`<?php print 'index.php/?page=search?query='.quote_replace(addmarks($search_results['did_you_mean'])).'&search=1'?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

### edit

try [rawurlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

Comment: @gabriel, It seems like urlencode can't handle question mark "?".